# What language should the following DFA recognise?

Tags: automata, finite-automata

[image]
My question is: what language should the following DFA recognise?

It seems that it should contain an odd number of substrings in the form 11*0. However, I am not sure whether there are any other conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrive at the answer by following all paths from the start state to the accepting state identifying the 'tail recursion':

```
  0*1+0+(1+0+1+0+)*
= 0*1*100*(1*100*1*100*)*
= 0*11*00*(11*00*11*00*)*
```

Intuitively, these are all strings over `{0,1}*` with an odd number of `10` substrings which is equivalent to the characterization you gave.